# CloudWatch alarm in ALARM state despite no data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a CloudWatch alarm based on the DynamoDB metric WriteThrottleEvents. There was a throttle datapoint in September which caused the alarm to enter the ALARM state, however there have been no other throttle datapoints since then, yet the alarm is still in ALARM state. The alarm previously had 'Treat Missing Data' set to `ignore` (which initially explained why it stayed in ALARM state), however I have now changed it to `missing`, yet the alarm is still in ALARM state, despite no datapoints. Why has it not changed state to 'INSUFFICIENT DATA'?
[image]

```
{
  "MetricAlarms": [
    {
      "AlarmName": "WriteThrottleEvents_Alarm",
      "AlarmArn": "******************",
      "AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp": "2021-02-25T20:07:44.960000+00:00",
      "ActionsEnabled": true,
      "OKActions": [],
      "AlarmActions": ["******************"],
      "InsufficientDataActions": [],
      "StateValue": "ALARM",
      "StateReason": "Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [1.0 (22/09/20 18:21:00)] was greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).",
      "StateReasonData": "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"queryDate\":\"2020-09-22T18:22:44.912+0000\",\"startDate\":\"2020-09-22T18:21:00.000+0000\",\"unit\":\"Count\",\"statistic\":\"Average\",\"period\":60,\"recentDatapoints\":[1.0],\"threshold\":1.0}",
      "StateUpdatedTimestamp": "2020-09-22T18:22:44.915000+00:00",
      "MetricName": "WriteThrottleEvents",
      "Namespace": "AWS/DynamoDB",
      "Statistic": "Average",
      "Dimensions": [
        {
          "Name": "TableName",
          "Value": "table-one"
        }
      ],
      "Period": 60,
      "Unit": "Count",
      "EvaluationPeriods": 1,
      "DatapointsToAlarm": 1,
      "Threshold": 1.0,
      "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
      "TreatMissingData": "missing"
    }
  ],
  "CompositeAlarms": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set [missing data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html#alarms-and-missing-data) to `notBreaching`. This way, lack of data points will be treated as good:

> Missing data points are treated as "good" and within the threshold,